# How to include target emulator in bash alias Cordova

Tags: ios, bash, cordova, alias

The regular way of running a Cordova project on a target emulator is as such:

```
cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-4s, 9.3"
```

I have a bash alias for running my project in iOS in my .bash_profile as:

```
alias ios_emulate='gulp --cordova '\''emulate ios -l'\'''
```

However, I want to be able to include the target in my alias because

```
ios_emulate --target="iPhone-4s, 9.3"
```

comes up with "No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-6s-Plus, 9.3 simulator". How can I incorporate whatever target emulator I specify into my alias? TYIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use a function, not an alias:

```
ios_emulate () {
    gulp --cordova 'emulate ios -l'
}
```

However, this is tricky to modify, since the quotes you use on the command line aren't really part of the argument; they just prevent the shell from performing word-splitting before calling your function. You need to add quotes in the right place manually.

I'm assuming that

```
ios_emulate --target="iPhone-4s, 9.3"
```

should behave the same as

```
gulp --cordova 'emulate ios -l --target="iPhone-4s, 9.3"'
```

One solution might be

```
ios_emulate () {
    cordova_arg="emulate ios -l"
    for arg; do
        cordova_arg+=" '$arg'"
    done
    gulp --cordova "$cordova_arg"
}
```

which builds up the argument string for `gulp` one argument at a time.